# PHP SQL query issue

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I have a system which is gathering all the people a user is following and also getting these peoples profile images, then displaying them on the webpage, however if a user is following 3 people, the query will loop three times for the first follower found then try and display each follower with the first followers image. Once this is has completed for each user, the query will move onto doing the same for the second follower, then each subsequent follower.

So basically the webpage looks like, 
[correct name and image for user 1] [correct name incorrect image for user 2] [correct name incorrect image for user 3]

[correct name incorrect image for user 1] [correct name and image for user 2] [correct name incorrect image for user 3]

and so on, depending on how many people a user is following. I feel I may not of explained this very well, if not please say and I shall rewrite

this is the code I am using

```
$sql_friends = "SELECT `first_name`, `surname`, `username` FROM users JOIN followers ON followers.friend_id = users.user_id WHERE followers.user_id = '$user_session_id'";
            $result_friends = mysql_query($sql_friends);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_friends)){
                $friendforename = $row['first_name'];
                $friendsurname = $row['surname'];
                $friendusername = $row['username'];
                $sql_img = "SELECT `img` FROM followers JOIN user_profile ON followers.friend_id = user_profile.user_id WHERE followers.user_id = '$user_session_id'";
                $result_img = mysql_query($sql_img);
                while($img_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_img)){
                    $friend_image = $img_row['img'];
                    echo "<a href=\"$friendusername/\"><img src=\"../{$friendusername}/{$friend_image}\" title=\"{$friendforename} {$friendsurname}\"/></a>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Quite aside: Assuming followers.user_id is an integer field, you don't need to put quotes around the variable.  You can just do followers.user_id = $user_session_id

Answer (score 0):

The second time you're calling `mysql_query()` will mess up the results of the first one. You'll have to either specify link identifiers for them or fetch all of the results of the first query into an array first, then iterate through that one to fetch the images.

However, I think you could also do a `LEFT JOIN user_profile` to get the images in the same query as the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two different queries to achieve this.(I assume there can be only one record per user in user_profile table).

try the code below:

```
 $sql_friends = "SELECT `first_name`, `surname`, `username`, `img` FROM users JOIN followers ON followers.friend_id = users.user_id LEFT JOIN user_profile ON followers.friend_id = user_profile.user_id WHERE followers.user_id = '$user_session_id'";
    $result_friends = mysql_query($sql_friends);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_friends)){
        $friendforename = $row['first_name'];
        $friendsurname = $row['surname'];
        $friendusername = $row['username'];
        $friend_image = $row['img'];        
        echo "<a href=\"$friendusername/\"><img src=\"../{$friendusername}/{$friend_image}\" title=\"{$friendforename} {$friendsurname}\"/></a>";
    }
```

Comment: this does only bring through only the three friends, but with no images, because the query is only telling it to select the `first_name`, `surname`, `username` FROM users, it also needs to select `img` from user_profile. How do I go about telling it to also select from this table without causing an error in the joins?

Comment: @Lit: Forgot to add img to original query. Updated the post now. Check it pls.

Comment: that is what I was trying, but the images are still blank, looking at the source `img` isn't being retrieved

Comment: Then looks like there are no corresponding records in the user_profile table for the friend users. Can you run the query directly and see if you are getting any results?

Comment: sorry I made a typo, your solution works great! thankyou for the help